# How to auto start a video using exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have a video loaded in a `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView` view but I want to make it automatically start when the view loads. Right now, the user has to click the play button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SimpleExoPlayer works well with a SurfaceView, there are methods to set the surface of the player.

This is how I create the SimpleExoPlayer:

```
/** Create a default TrackSelector **/
TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new Handler());

/** Create a default LoadControl **/
LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

/** Create the player **/
mPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector, loadControl);

/** Make the ExoPlayer play when its data source is prepared **/
mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

I hold these factories so I don't have to create them each time I set a new data source.

```
/** Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data **/
mExtractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

/** Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded **/
mDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
        context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "AppName")
);
```

I use the following method to set a new data source on the player. This method uses the factories created earlier.

For me, the `String source` is a URI to an MP4 file held on the device's SD card. Having `setPlayWhenReady(true)` earlier, once this video is prepared & ready to play it will begin immediately.

```
public void setDataSource(SurfaceView view, String source) {
    stopMedia();
    mPlayer.setVideoSurfaceView(view);
    view.requestFocus();

    // Create the media source
    mVideoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.fromFile(
            new File(source)),
            mDataSourceFactory, mExtractorsFactory, null, null);

    // Prepare the player with the source.
    mPlayer.prepare(mVideoSource);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just use:

```
player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);
```