# How can i play video in recyclerview when it is visible and pause as soon as it goes invisible (Scrolled)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer, video-player

i have a heterogeneous recyclerview like facebook does (text,images,videos), i have implemented exoplayer for playing videos in it, it works fine but the problem arises when i scroll a playing video as its video is not visible but its audio continues playing until it is finished.
I have the same recyclerview structure as suggested by android docs (ViewholderClass, adapterclass, and ActivityClass) as...
Main class : fetch the conent from firebase,
Viewholder class : checks the post type and show accordingly,
Adapter class : the usual methods to bind data,
In short the problem with viewholder is there are not lifecycle methods available and i cannot get the object reference in adapter class to pause it in onDetachedFromRecyclerView(). i tried all the stackoverflow answers but nothing worked. i dont have much experience in android so if anyone can show some sample code that will be extremely helpful,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So solve your issue step by step

1. Get which item is visible on the screen
   So to get which item is visible on your screen you can use following methods

   ```
   int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
   int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
   int findLastVisibleItemPosition();
   int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
   ```

by using LayoutManager attached with your recyclerview, for Ex.:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
int visiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

so now using `visiblePosition` you can get your item from adapter

2. Now start and pause video which is visible on the screen

   - Start video from item which is visible on the screen ref. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57631116/8240915)
   - Pause video which is scrolled up or down ref. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54905612/8240915)